# Unity in c# errors with "the type does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

This is the problematic line

```
datosAguardar datos = new datosAguardar ();
```

Here is my code

```
public class estadoJuego : MonoBehaviour {

public int puntuacionMaxima = 0;
public static estadoJuego estadojuego; 
private string rutaArchivo; 

void Awake ()
{
    rutaArchivo = Application.persistentDataPath + "/datos.dat";
    if (estadojuego == null) 
    {
        estadojuego = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

    }  else if (estadojuego != this) 
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    cargar ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void guardar ()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Create (rutaArchivo);

    datosAguardar datos = new datosAguardar ();

    datos.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima; 

    bf.Serialize (file, datos);

    file.Close ();
}


void cargar () 
{
    if (File.Exists (rutaArchivo)) 
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Open (rutaArchivo,FileMode.Open);

        datosAguardar datos = (datosAguardar)bf.Deserialize (file);

        puntuacionMaxima = datos.puntuacionMaxima; 

        file.Close ();
    }  else 
    {
        puntuacionMaxima = 0; 
    }
}


[Serializable]
//definiendo la clase
class datosAguardar  //: ISerializable 

{
    //propiedades de la clase
    public int puntuacionMaxima ; 
    //metodo de la clase
    //constructor de la clase
    public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima) // : base (puntuacionMaxima)
    {       

        this.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima  ;
    }

}
```

This is the constructor

```
[Serializable]
//definiendo la clase
class datosAguardar  //: ISerializable 

{
    //propiedades de la clase
    public int puntuacionMaxima ; 
    //metodo de la clase
    //constructor de la clase
    public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima) // : base (puntuacionMaxima)
    {       

        this.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima  ;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error that Unity is giving you?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. This question is not specific to game development and thus should be asked on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The datosAguardar class only has a contructor that takes 1 argument:

```
public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima)
```

so you either need to supply that argument, e.g.

```
datosAguardar datos = new datosAguardar (5);
```

or define another constructor that takes no arguments, e.g.:

```
public datosAguardar ()
{       

    this.puntuacionMaxima = 7;
}
```

or give the parameter in the existing constructor a default value, e.g.:

```
public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima = 8)
{       

    this.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid answering off topic questions :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, the time stamps show that you commented on this answer *before* voting to close. I have to ask if you would have *known* this was a generic programming problem, if you had not read the answer in the first place. [Related meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/do-we-still-consider-programming-questions-off-topic-if-the-context-is-game-dev)

Comment: @Gnemlock Do you mean _"if you had not read the **question** in the first place"_?